# TypeError: Cannot read property 'qtt' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, typeerror

> Na hora da execução a linha let calculation, onde tem list[1].qtt, mostra o erro do título acima, o projeto é uma lista onde retorna o valor da compra multiplicado pela quantidade, peso e valor dos produtos dividido igualmente entre os emails(clients);

```
function challenge() {

let list = [

    {
        price: 2,
        qtt: 2,
        weigth: 4
    },
    
]

let clients = [

    {email: "email@email.com"}

]

let calculation = (list[0].price * **list[1].qtt** * list[2].weigth) / clients.length

let form = calculation.toLocaleString(`pt-BR`, {style: `currency`, currency: `BRL`})

if(clients.length === 0) {
    console.log("Type client email")
}

else {
    console.log(form)
}


for(let i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${clients[i].email} = ${form}`)
}
```

}
challenge()

Comment: Your list only has a single element (which is at `list[0]`). There is no `list[1]` or `list[2]`.

Comment: Also, posts on Stack Overflow [are required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). You can use [pt.so] if you want to ask it in Portuguese (as long as the question is on-topic there of course).

Comment: You should use `list[0]` for all the properties, not `list[1]` and `list[2]`.